# how to config default ipv6 route using route command

Tags: macos, networking, routes, ipv6, bsd

My system is macOS, I try to use `/sbin/route` to confing some custom route, I know `0.0.0.0` is the default ipv4 route, so I can delete/change/add the default ipv4 route by running `route delete 0.0.0.0`.

Then I searched wiki and I found the default route address of ipv6 is `::` or `::/0`, I try to delete the route by running `route delete ::` or `route delete ::/0`, It returns `route: bad address: ::`.

My ipv6 route table is:

```
Internet6:
Destination                             Gateway                         Flags         Netif Expire
default                                 fe80::3600:a3ff:fed3:93e5%en0   UGcI            en0
default                                 fe80::%utun0                    UGcI          utun0
::1                                     ::1                             UHL             lo0
```

The question is what is the `default` value and how I can change it?

Comment: Oh, just realised this question is on the wrong site after answering it. Can somebody please move this over to Superuser? Thanks, and apologies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case `default` means `::/0`. When manipulating IPv6 routes with the `route` command don't forget to specify `-inet6` so that it knows you're talking about the IPv6 routing table.

The following commands should all work for you:

```
sudo route delete -inet6 default
sudo route delete -inet6 ::/0
sudo route delete -inet6 default fe80::3600:a3ff:fed3:93e5%en0
sudo route delete -inet6 ::/0 fe80::3600:a3ff:fed3:93e5%en0
```

They should all remove the default IPv6 route entry from your `en0` interface.